# Remove Eclipse Environment Variable programmatically Plugin Development

Tags: c++, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently developing an plugin which must remove a Eclipse Environment variable, for now i have this:

```
public static void removeEnvironmentVariable(IProject proj, String variable) {
    // environment path
    ICProjectDescription prjDesc = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescription(proj);  

    IEnvironmentVariableManager envManager = 
            CCorePlugin.getDefault().getBuildEnvironmentManager(); 
    IContributedEnvironment contribEnv = envManager.getContributedEnvironment(); 

    // We must iterate through all configurations 
    for(ICConfigurationDescription config : prjDesc.getConfigurations()) {
        contribEnv.removeVariable(variable, config);
    }

    // Save the changes to the environment 
    try {
        CoreModel.getDefault().setProjectDescription(proj, prjDesc);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Am I wrong to think that ICProjectDescription, IEnvironmentVariableManager, ICConfigurationDescription... are part of CDT, for C/C++ plugin ?

Comment: You're right, I'm using to remove a variable from a C/C++ project

Comment: Please change the tags then, it will help you (so that people watching c++ tags see your question). You should add these: eclipse-cdt, cdt and C++